# Зачем нужны [комментарии] в заголовке на Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, заголовок

Встречал некоторые заголовки в вопросах с комментариями в квадратных скобках. Например:

1. [Требует правки]
2. [Закрыт]

Кто делает такие комментарии?
В каких случаях?
Какие комментарии ещё есть?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При [закрытии вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) в зависимости от причины закрытия в заголовке появляется соответствующая приписка.

Это действие производит система автоматически.